# How to escape php mysqli query?

Tags: php, mysqli

I am passing data from AJAX to my PHP. I just run a `for` loop to make my query. Problem with my data is that it contains single quote.

I am using single quote to enclose my parameters in the query. Query is something like

```
   INSERT INTO myTable (column1.column2) VALUES('value1', 'value2'), 
   ('value'1', 'value2');
```

I want to escape like

```
   INSERT INTO myTable (column1.column2) VALUES('value1', 'value2'), 
   ('value\'1', 'value2');
```

I just tried `mysqli_real_Escape_String`. It returns something like

```
   INSERT INTO myTable (column1.column2) VALUES(\'value1\', \'value2\'), 
   (\'value\'1\', \'value2\');
```

So Query execution fails.

I don't think using `htmlspeciachars` is the right way for this.

Any suggestions?

Comment: I recommend you to use [PDO](http://php.net/manual/fr/book.pdo.php) to access DB in PHP.
If you won't, you can use [mysql_escape_string](http://php.net/manual/fr/function.mysql-escape-string.php)

Comment: Use prepared statements - both mysqli and PDO support them and it will make life soooo much easier once you get the hang of them

Comment: I don't think I can use parameters. Since number of rows and number of columns are dynamic. I am using mysqli_query only

Answer (score 1):

You should definitely be using prepared statements. They're not that tricky.

However, if you're not going to make that jump then you just need to use `mysqli_real_escape_string` properly.

From the result you got, I'm guessing you wrapped the whole query in the `mysqli_real_escape_string` function. However you should just wrap the value in it.

i.e.

```
"INSERT INTO myTable (column1, column2) VALUES('value1', 'value2'), 
   ('" . mysql_real_escape_string("value'1") . "', 'value2')";
```

Thats a pretty contrived way of doing things. But the idea is: only wrap the value in `mysqli_real_escape_string()`.